# Centering asp:menu item's when there are multiple rows of menu items

Tags: asp.net, css, aspmenu-control

you can replicate my problem with this small code snippet.

```
    <div ID="topcell" runat="server" align="center" style="text-align:center">
   <asp:Menu ID="testmenu" runat="server" Width="300px" Orientation="Horizontal" RenderingMode="List">

    <Items>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Testing"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Testing"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Testing"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Testing"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Testing"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Testing"></asp:MenuItem>



    </Items>
   </asp:Menu>
   </div>
```

Result:

- Testing-Testing-Testing-Testing-Testing-Testing
- Testing----------------------------------------

Desired results:

- Testing-Testing-Testing-Testing-Testing-Testing
- ------------------Testing----------------------

I have tried all three RenderingModes with no luck!  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding following CSS to your page:

```
<style type="text/css" >
   #testmenu ul li {
      display:inline-block;
      float:none !important;
   }
</style>
```

It will overwrite inline menu styles and force the unordered list to center.